# Why does an initializer list cause 2 copies of data and not just the a single copy to pass it to the function?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

If we create a simple dummy-class as follows:

```
struct example {
    example() { std::cout << "Create" << std::endl; }
    example(const exam&) { std::cout << "Copy" << std::endl; }
    example(example &&) noexcept { std::cout << "Move" << std::endl; }
}
```

And pass it in an initialization list (`std::initializer_list<example>`):

```
some_function({example()});
```

The output (from GCC/C++11) is:

```
Create
Copy
Copy
```

This doesn't make sense to me as you create the example object itself then pass it through an `initializer_list`. This means that you have the original object, your list has a copy of the object and your function has a copy of the *list* (not the example object) hinting that it should be a single create of your object then a single copy of the initializer list.

Expected output (without the extra copy):

```
Create (from example())
Copy (into initializer_list)
```

TL;DR: Why does passing my object through an initializer list instantiate two copies of the object instead of one if the object getting passed in the initializer list itself?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

struct example {
    example() { std::cout << "Create" << std::endl; }
    example(const example &) { std::cout << "Copy" << std::endl; }
    example(example &&) noexcept { std::cout << "Move" << std::endl; }
};

void some_function(std::initializer_list<example> input) {
    for (example exam : input) {
        std::cout << &exam << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    example exam;
    some_function({exam});
}
```

Comment: Post a complete, compilable example of what  you are asking about.

Comment: How do you know the 2nd copy is coming from the `initializer_list` itself? What is `some_function()` actually doing with the list? How is `some_function()` even declared?

Comment: I'll edit and append an example for @NeilButterworth.

Comment: @NeilButterworth http://cpp.sh/4rboi

Comment: @RandyThompson, please copy the code from the link and paste it in your post.

Comment: Post code here.

Comment: I give up, toxic place to try and learn

Comment: Or maybe it's just you?

Comment: @NeilButterworth ;)

Comment: There are over half a million posts tagged C++ on SO. If you want people to give you their time for free to help you, you need to make as easy as possible for us. I see that you've improved your post so I'm giving up an upvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second copy has nothing to do with initializer list itself. The second copy is created inside your `some_function` when you iterate your list "by value"

```
for (example exam : input) {
    std::cout << &exam << std::endl;
}
```

If you iterate it "by const reference" instead the secondy copy will disappear.

Comment: Bam. Silly mistake. Thank you!

Comment: I could not reproduce - I got no copy at all - only create